# Signature PADES sequential or parallel

Tags: java, digital-signature, pades

In signature CAdES it's possible create multiple signature sequential or parallel.

**Signature parallel**: in case of contract, when more people have to sign the same document. Each people sign the same document, and each signature is added to document.

**Signature sequential**: where person sign the entire document (signature including) previously signed from another person.

My question is: in signature PAdES it's possible to create signature parallel?
For signature PAdES we use itext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible, PAdES signatures are always sequential. Each signature is made on the current version of the document

Take a look to the [ETSI TS 102 778-1 PDF Advanced Electronic Signature Profiles](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277801/01.01.01_60/ts_10277801v010101p.pdf)

> **4.4 PDF serial signatures**
>
> [image: pades]
>
> **Signatures applied in parallel are currently not supported**